# Multiple file upload not working (Material UI Dropzone ^3.4.0, axios)

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am not able to upload multiple files using [Material UI dropzonze](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-dropzone).

The API works fine with postman.

This is my console when I log the `formData`:

[image: Log of formData]

This is where I am using it:

[image: Use of component]

This is how I am setting state:

[image: Setting state of files]

This is how I am trying to send request:
(I also tried appending `files` only, and that didn't work too)

[image: AJAX Request]

When I log `files1.files`, I get this:

[image: Files Log]

Comment: recommend react-uploady. Much easier to use :) with multiple file support and nested folder drag&drop out of the box

Comment: Thank you so much!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the solution out by appending the files as a `value` of `formData` function one by one with the same `key` (i.e. images) instead of sending the the array of images at once as a `value` with the `key` (i.e. images).

So actually, I was supposed to do this:

```
files1.files.forEach(file => {
        formData.append('images', file); // appending image one by one for the same key
      });
```

instead of this:

```
formData.append('images', files1.files); // appending the whole array
```